# Can someone help me with JavaFX and inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx

I just finished my second java class and I'm trying to make my own program utilizing MVC.  I am trying to put all my code for my events in a separate class other than the GUI class.  But I can't get it to work right. If I put the code in the `doAction()` in the GUI class it works fine, but when I try to override it won't work.

I feel like maybe I need to instantiate an object but of type `TestController` but I can't seem to get that to work right either.

I am trying to use a class for a controller.

The first code is snippets from the GUI. I think my problem is:

```
fileNewConnection.setOnAction(this::doAction)
```

**TestGUI**

```
package testNinja;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class TestGUI extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}  //  end main

public Stage window;
public Menu fileMenu;
public MenuItem fileNewConnection;
public MenuBar menuBar;
 
public void start(Stage stage) {
    window = stage;
    fileMenu = new Menu("File");
    fileNewConnection = new MenuItem("New Connection");
    fileMenu.getItems().add(fileNewConnection);
    fileNewConnection.setOnAction(this::doAction);
    menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);

    VBox topPane = new VBox(16, menuBar);
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(topPane, 500, 300);
    stage.setTitle("Test Ninja"); 
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}  //  end start

public void doAction(ActionEvent evt) {
     
/*
* Object source = evt.getSource();
*    
* if (source == fileNewConnection )  {
*           
*      System.out.println("You clicked the "+ ((MenuItem) source).getText() + " Menu        Item ");
*        }
*/
     
}  //  end do Action`
```

**TestController**

```
package testNinja;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

public class TestController extends TestGUI{

@Override
public void doAction(ActionEvent evt) { 
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source == fileNewConnection )  {
        System.out.println("You clicked the "+ ((MenuItem) source).getText() + " Menu Item ");       
    }    
}  //  end do Action

}  //  end class
```

Comment: What you have will work if your main program creates a `TestController` instance as the main window, not `TestGUI`.  Either than or skip the inheritance and have your `TestGUI` create an instance of `TestController`, and just forward the callback along.

Comment: Note it does not make sense for `TestController` to extend `TestGUI`. The latter class is your application class and represents the application itself and its lifecycle. It is not a controller. Plus, in a typical setup, JavaFX will instantiate the application class for you, which is `TestGUI` in this case. As far as I can tell, nothing here will result in `TestController` being instantiated.

Comment: It sounds like you have some significant misunderstandings about inheritance, though there’s not enough information here to understand what those misunderstandings really are. MVC and inheritance are pretty much orthogonal concepts: they don’t have anything to do with each other (though both ideas could occur in place in the same application).

Comment: There are numerous books, courses and online resources available on topics such as object-oriented development, inheritance, Java, JavaFX, design patterns, and the model view controller pattern subset. Treating the topics separately and sometimes combined.  I won’t recommend resources in this instance as it is off-topic.  I recommend you do some research  and find quality resources and tutorials on the mentioned topics,  doing lots of exercise and practice before continuing with your current course.